Is working for a fintech company that sells software to banks, halal?
The company is a 'financial experience company'.
Essentially what they do is provide digital banking solutions to financial institutions, including banks and other fintechs.
Here's a breakdown of what they offer:
Digital Banking Platforms: They provide software that allows financial institutions to offer online and mobile banking services, including account management, bill pay, and transfers.
Lending Solutions: They help banks and credit unions streamline their lending processes, from loan applications to origination and servicing.
Payments and Transfers: They offer solutions for handling various payment types, such as checks, ACH transfers, and P2P payments.
Data Analytics: They provide tools to help financial institutions analyze customer data and gain insights into their behavior, preferences, and needs.
Fraud Prevention: They offer solutions to help protect financial institutions and their customers from fraud.
They simply sell the platforms and software that allow the institutions to do all this stuff in a good looking UI.
Would working at this company in IT be permissible?
To be clear this company does not provide any financial services itself. The only part of it that might deal directly with riba is the lending solutions part. Which is what I'm worried about.
